# Ruby equivalent to func_get_args()

Tags: php, ruby, debugging, methods

In many PHP-application, when things are badly documented or weird implemented, the function [func_get_args()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) comes to resque. It allows me to inspect (or print) what variables are passed along to a function

```
function poorly_documented($op, $a2, $a3 = 'default', $rest) {
  var_dump(func_get_args());
  // ...
}
```

Allthough in Ruby I hardly ever need this, due to the nature of the language, I sometimes like to inspect what is passed along.

How would I do that in Ruby, or Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this website](http://railsforphp.com/reference/funchand/func_get_args) should be of great service to you.

```
def add(*nums)
  total = 0
  nums.each {|num| total += num }
  total
end
# => 6
```